# Using selenium to access a web page's context menu

Tags: java, selenium

I can see the context menu open, but I am not able to select an item within the menu. Here is my code:

```java
selenium.contextMenu("//table[1]/tbody/tr[@id='selectionItem']/td[2]/div/table/tbody/tr/td[@id='cell_table_1_2']");    
selenium.focus("//iframe[@menutype='ContextMenu']");    
selenium.click("//div[text()='Duplicate']");
```

The log shows "Got result: OK" for all the 3 commands above.
I am using Selenium 2.0 on IE8. I have `Thread.sleep(5000)` between each command above for some delay.

Comment: you will probably need to post the HTML code of your page as well, otherwise we will have no idea what can be wrong. My guess is that your selector (locator) for the menu item is wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you haven't linked to the actual code, we can only guess.

Have you tried creating appropriate MouseOver events in order to bring up the menu options? I ran into this on one of our internal applications, and using the Mouse* commands was how I got around it..